# Below is the folder and file structure, in which I have move all the files with keeping its sub folder structure excluding few files and sub folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZGnQ.png)I am really facing difficulty in writing Powershell script to move my application code from one server to another server.
Below is the folder and file structure, in which I have move all the files with keeping its sub folder structure excluding few files and sub folder.

Server 1

\\networkshardpath\D$\MyProject

Main Folder :   Folder A, B, C,D,E,F,G

Files : File 1, File 2, File 3, File 4

Sub Folder A : File A1, File A2, File A3 etc

Sub Folder B : File B1, File B2, File B3, File B4

Sub Folder C & D : Lots of log files which I need to exclude.

Sub Folder E : File E1, File E2, File E3,

Now I want a script which copies all the files and folder keeping same structure excluding below mentioned folders and files on Server 2 with network path like \server2\D$\MyProject2\ .

Exclude Folders : C,D,G

Exclude Files:

From Main Folder : File4

From Sub Folder A : A3

From Sub Folder B : B4

During this activity, 1 log file needs to be generated which will helps me to keep track of all the files details, like which files copied and which are excluded. During this if any error occurs then the detailed error details with time.

Please help me with this script or please guide me to get this resolved.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why can't you manually do it in FAR Manager or Explorer? It might take 10-1000 times less time than writing a script.

Comment: `robocopy` for the win?

Comment: Hi, have you written any code ? Please edit your question to include it

Comment: I am new to this forum, hence don't know how to write code on this page hence I have attached screen shot of my PS1 code. Please check and suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I have written below mentioned code. Main purpose is to avoid login into RDP server and doing all the deployments from the local system. This code is working fine but its working very slow from system, but the same is working very fast from application server.

Now 1 more thing is that, on my local system we are having very limited access and UAC access is disabled by Administrator. Please suggest me how to run this script with the help of batch file or any other way just by double clicking on it.